# Updating Values in A Multidimensional Cart Array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, session-variables, cart

I am writing a custom shopping cart in PHP, I add product info to the cart session like this:

```
$product_array=array($title,$price,$qty);
if(!isset($_SESSION['cart']))
$_SESSION['cart']=array();

if(!in_array($product_array,$_SESSION['cart']))
$_SESSION['cart'][]=$product_array;
else
{
// update price and quantity here
}
```

My challenge: I want to update the price and quantity($qty) of the product if it already exists in 
$_SESSION['cart'] array rather than adding it. Something like this

```
price = price + $price,
qty = qty + $qty
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This example is similar to your example. you can add code from foreach loop  in else condition. I am considering product_id instead of $title variable.

```
 $_SESSION['cart'][] = [ 'product_id'=> 12, 'price' => 100 , 'quantity' => 2 ];
 $_SESSION['cart'][] = [ 'product_id'=> 11, 'price' => 200, 'quantity' => 3 ];

    $product_array = ['product_id' => 11, 'price'=> 200, 'quantity' => 4 ];
    foreach( $_SESSION['cart'] as $key => $value ) {
      if( $value['product_id']  == $product_array['product_id']) {
         $_SESSION['cart'][$key]['quantity'] = $value['quantity'] + $product_array['quantity'];
           $_SESSION['cart'][$key]['price'] = $value['price'] + $product_array['price'];
        }
    }
print_r($_SESSION);
```

Output before updating product :

```
Array
(
    [cart] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [product_id] => 12
                    [price] => 100
                    [quantity] => 2
                )
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [product_id] => 11
                    [price] => 200
                    [quantity] => 3
                )
        )
)
```

Output after adding new product in session.

```
Array
(
    [cart] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [product_id] => 12
                    [price] => 100
                    [quantity] => 2
                )
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [product_id] => 11
                    [price] => 400
                    [quantity] => 7
                )
        )
)
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way I can just update the concerned elements within the multidimensional array without looping through it? I already know that those elements exist there.

Comment: And what of the case that the product is NOT in the cart session. How would you state $_SESSION['cart']

Comment: I already mentioned that add my code in else condition. If product is not in cart then your if condition will work

Comment: I have another way of implement cart functionality. You can add key as product id & quantity as value against that product key. You can try in that way. If you can't find solution, I will provide you code for same.

Comment: If you implement with above logic then you don't need to add for loop  while adding product in cart